# Problems with page number position with subfigures

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats, page

I am making three subfigures below one another on one page. I managed to get the figures look how I want, but the page number shifted from its default position centered in the footer to the top right of the page and I can't get it back to the footer. I changed the footskip and textheight in my document, but that did not help. If I have this figure in my document, all other pages have correct page number position but just the page with the figure has the page number top right. Do you have any ideas how to make the page number appear in the centre of footer?
Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, bm} %better typesetting of mathematical expressions, theorems, additional symbols
\usepackage{booktabs}%fixltx2e}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false % <-- important
]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib} %standard package for bibliography
\usepackage{hyperref} %hyperlink support


\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=4pt} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage[textheight=700pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}





\graphicspath{ {"some path"} }

\newenvironment{spmatrix}[1]
 {\def\mysubscript{#1}\mathop\bgroup\begin{bmatrix}}
 {\end{bmatrix}\egroup_{\textstyle\mathstrut\scriptstyle\mysubscript}}


\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00},bookmarksnumbered,hypertexnames=false} %zoom: default screen; numbers for bookmarks

\setlength\parindent{34pt}
\onehalfspacing





%\renewcommand\Authands{ and }
\date{\today}
%\bibliographystyle{stylebib}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\footskip}{\paperheight
  -(1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\textheight)
  -0.4in}
\begin{document}

\clubpenalty 9999 %no orphants (typographic properties)
\widowpenalty 9999 %no widows (typographic properties)
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi} %shortcut for Stata tables


\newpage
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing






\begin{figure}
\begin{footnotesize}
\centering
\textbf{}\par\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \textbf{Graph 1}\par\medskip
  \includegraphics{sub1}
  %\caption{}
  %\label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
  \vspace*{-8em}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \textbf{Graph 2}\par\medskip
  \includegraphics{sub2}
  %\caption{}
  %\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
 \vspace*{-8em}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \textbf{Graph 3}\par\medskip
  \includegraphics{sub3}
  %\caption{}
  %\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Here is the caption}
\label{fig:sample figure}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and it produces:

[image]

so there seems to be a lot of space in the bottom of the page below the figure, but still the page number appears top right.

Comment: Off-topic: You're loading some packages twice and `hyperref` is loaded too early. Please simplify your example to the minimum version that still compiles and still shows the issue

Comment: According to its documentation,  the package `floatpag` 'provides commands to apply different pagestyles to the full page floats'. If you don't want this, simply remove this package from your preamble.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped a lot & was so easy. Yes, I need to remove some unnecessary packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the default is `\floatpagestyle{headings}`. You can change it to

```
\floatpagestyle{plain}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: With the example in the question, there does not seem to be any difference to not using `floatpag` at all. Is there an effect I seem to overlook?

Comment: @leandriis: You're right, I've just tested (I never used this package before). The aim of the package is just to define pagestyles for full page floats.